# listFiles not workig after exporting to jar

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, jar

I am working on a `libgdx` game using tiled to make the maps, in my level select screen I read in all the files in the map folder and count the files ending with `.tmx` to see how many level buttons I have to make.

All of this has been working fine but when I try to export the project to a jar using the intellij gradle dist command it just stops working.

I'm guessing it changes the path to the files or something when it's exporting it but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is the code that reads the files

```
        new File("maps").listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if (name.endsWith(".tmx")) {
                numberOfLevels++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the `maps` folder inside the JAR?

Comment: Where are your maps? `new File("maps")` will look for the directory in the current working directory which I suspect is not what you want

Comment: The maps folder is inside the JAR, it is in "Game -> core -> assets -> maps"

Comment: It finds everything else like textures/sounds/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of `.tmx` files within the jar, try treating it as a zip and counting the number of files of interest, like so:

```java
List<String> classNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/jar/file.jar"));
int numberOfLevels=0;
for (ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zip.getNextEntry()) {
    if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".tmx")) {
        numberOfLevels++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no idea how long I have been googling trying to find an answer to this, thank you so much you just saved me from going completely insane from this!

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

To access "maps" like that it may not be included within the jar file, but needs to be in the same directory as the jar is. With `new File(...)` you are accessing the PC's file system, which cannot find a "maps" file as it is compiled within the jar file